# What is the type of sequence comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have just started to learn Scala.

When I was playing with an example in http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111 , I found a problem in types.

```
object Main extends App {
  def even(from: Int, to: Int): Vector[Int] =
    for (i <- from until to if i % 2 == 0) yield i

  Console.println(even(0, 20).getClass())
}
```

This does not compile with the following error.

```
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]
 required: Vector[Int]
           for (i <- from until to if i % 2 == 0) yield i
                  ^
```

However, without type specification of return value, It works and the class is Vector.

```
object Main extends App {
  def even(from: Int, to: Int) =
    for (i <- from until to if i % 2 == 0) yield i

  Console.println(even(0, 20).getClass()) // => class scala.collection.immutable.Vector
}
```

This seems to be contradict.
Let me know what is the cause of the compile type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing classes with types. The type of the value yielded by the for-expression is `IndexedSeq[Int]`, which happens to be implemented by a Vector instance. You specified in the signature that the return *type* must be `Vector[Int]`, but the for-expression gives no such guarantee.

edit to add: you'll notice in the example on the website that they use the `List.range` method to produce the generator in the for-expression, and that's how they get a return type of `List[Int]`. If you use the `Vector.range` method (rather than the `until` method, which produces a `Range`) then you will be filtering a `Vector` and the compiler will infer this as the return type.

If you want to see they type of an expression or function, the REPL tells you when you define or evaluate it:

```
scala> def even(from: Int, to: Int) =
     |   for (i <- from until to if i % 2 == 0) yield i
even: (from: Int, to: Int)scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]
                       // ^ here!
```

Comment: I think that, more importantly, he's confusing compile time information with run time information.

Answer (score 2):

Luigi's answer is correct, but maybe needs a bit more explanation. The runtime type is indeed `Vector[Int]`, but the compiler doesn't know this. The for expression is equivalent to

```
from.until(to).filter(_%2==0)
```

So it creates a Range and then calls the filter method on it. As you can see in the API documentation, the filter method of `Range` is declared as returning an `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: Thanks.  I prefer higher-order methods to list-comprehension syntax.  It is more understandable.

Comment: Would it be more correct to say the runtime type is `Vector[_]` since type parameters are erased?